# Keep Changes in SQLite Permanently

Tags: r, sqlite, r-markdown

Hello I am fairly new to the world of relational databases and SQLite, but I am in the process of trying to edit and combine multiple datasets in SQLite in R Markdown, and I was wondering if there is any way to make each change permanent. For example, in my first select statement here

```
SELECT id, avg(days) Average
FROM data1
GROUP BY id
```

And then after I have the column of averages, I would like to join one column from another dataset using the primary key like below:

```
SELECT data1.*, data2.purchases
FROM data1
LEFT JOIN data2
ON data1.id=data2.id
```

But I want the changes from the first set to be permanent and applied when I try to alter the table further. Is there something that I am doing wrong? This is all in the SQLite insert in R markdown, so could my syntax also be causing this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "But I want the changes from the first set to be permanent and applied when I try to alter the table further." What does that mean? "Is there something that I am doing wrong?" I don't know, what problem are you encountering?

Comment: @hobbs Sorry, my language is confusing. Okay, so my first data set has two columns one with the id's and then another with corresponding days. Some id's have more than one day so I made SQL print the ids and the average of the days . Now from this NEW altered dataset (the one with the id, and averages) i want to add another column. But when I go to add the new column, it adds from the ORIGINAL dataset (the one with the id's and their multiple days).

Comment: Are the data1 and data2 the same table or two different tables?

Comment: @hobbs let me try to paint a better picture. In the beginning, I have column A and column B. Then I perform alterations and that prints A and B*. Then I want to do a left join of one column, I want that to print A and B* and C (As opposed to A and B and C). And then I want to add 3 more columns. I want that to print A B* C D E F (as opposed to it printing A B D E F).

Comment: @Psidom, they are two different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the result from the first selection an alias, i.e. A and then join it with another table `data2`. Usually you don't want to save the selection you made to data base, which will mess up your data base very quickly:

*Nested Selection*:

```
SELECT A.*, data2.purchases
FROM
(
    SELECT id, avg(days) Average
    FROM data1
    GROUP BY id
) A
LEFT JOIN data2
ON A.id = data2.id
```

---

You can create a temporary table though, which is valid for your current connection to the data base:

*Create A Temporary table*:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE A AS
SELECT id, avg(days) Average
FROM data1
GROUP BY id
```

Then you can use it as:

```
SELECT A.*, data2.purchases
FROM A
LEFT JOIN data2
ON A.id=data2.id
```

---

Normally, you will not be able to create a permanent table in the data base unless you are the maintainer of the data base and have the permission to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Does this mean that anytime I want to add something to the data set I have to do a nested select? I have about 4 more operations I want to perform on the dataset and I want them all to be combined in a single dataset with all my alterations.

Comment: I listed two options above, you can use nested select or you can create a temp table for every operation you made and then refer to them later on.

Comment: Okay, so for example for the first alteration I create temp table A. Then the second alteration I call on temp table A and create the temp table B and so on?

Comment: Yes. If you want to make things clearer than nested select. And you can save these tables permanently if you have the write permission to the data base and it is worth the effort, i.e, they will likely be used many times.